# SELECT statement where rows are omitted based on another table

Tags: sql, select

Table with orders has another table with positions. I want the orders table to show but then only have the most up to-date position on it. Below is a picture of the 3 rows I want showing. Omit the rest.

[image]

```
SELECT DispatchTable.ordernumber, DispatchTable.truck,
       DispatchTable.driver, DispatchTable.actualpickup, 
       DispatchTable.actualdropoff, orders.pickupdateandtime, 
       orders.dropoffdateandtime, Truck002.lastposition, 
       Truck002.lastdateandtime
FROM DispatchTable 
INNER JOIN orders ON DispatchTable.ordernumber = orders.id 
INNER JOIN Truck002 ON DispatchTable.truck = Truck002.name
WHERE (orders.status = 'onRoute')
```

Comment: How is C# involved here? The tag doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: My project uses C#, sorry about that. Clearly this question does not. First time posting on this site. Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want the row having the latest `lastdateandtime` for the truck `name`, this should work:

```
SELECT DispatchTable.ordernumber,
       DispatchTable.truck,
       DispatchTable.driver,
       DispatchTable.actualpickup,
       DispatchTable.actualdropoff,
       orders.pickupdateandtime,
       orders.dropoffdateandtime,
       TruckLatest.lastposition,
       TruckLatest.lastdateandtime
  FROM DispatchTable
 INNER JOIN orders ON DispatchTable.ordernumber = orders.id
 INNER JOIN (SELECT name,
                    lastposition,
                    lastdateandtime
               FROM Truck002 Truck1
              WHERE lastdateandtime =
                    (SELECT MAX(lastdateandtime)
                       FROM Truck002 Truck2
                      WHERE Truck2.name = Truck1.name)) TruckLatest
         ON DispatchTable.truck = TruckLatest.name
 WHERE (orders.status = 'onRoute')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can get the most recent record for a truck using `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT dt.ordernumber, dt.truck,
       dt.driver, dt.actualpickup, 
       dt.actualdropoff, o.pickupdateandtime, 
       o.dropoffdateandtime, t.lastposition, 
       t.lastdateandtime
FROM DispatchTable dt INNER JOIN
     orders o
     ON dt.ordernumber = o.id INNER JOIN
     (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.name ORDER BY t.lastdateandtime DESC) as seqnum
      FROM Truck002 t
     ) t
     ON dt.truck = t.name
WHERE o.status = 'onRoute' AND seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: This worked brilliantly. Very sorry for the confusing Table name.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, why are you using `Truck002`'s `name` field rather than its `id` field as the link to `DispacthTable`?  This is considered a less efficient way of doing it than using `id` (which is either a numerical field or a shorter string than `name`).

Secondly, you should mention in your Question that each `Order` can have many `DispatchTable`'s and that each `DispacthTable` can have many `Truck002`'s, otherwise many people will start by assuming that it is the other way round between `DispatchTable` and `Truck002`.

Thirdly, please try...

```
SELECT DispatchTable.ordernumber,
       DispatchTable.truck,
       DispatchTable.driver,
       DispatchTable.actualpickup,
       DispatchTable.actualdropoff,
       orders.pickupdateandtime,
       orders.dropoffdateandtime,
       Truck002.lastposition, 
       Truck002.lastdateandtime
FROM DispatchTable 
INNER JOIN orders ON DispatchTable.ordernumber = orders.id 
INNER JOIN Truck002 ON DispatchTable.truck = Truck002.name
WHERE (orders.status = 'onRoute')
GROUP BY ordernumber
HAVING lastdateandtime = MAX( lastdateandtime )
```

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

*Further Reading*

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177906(v=office.12).aspx (on `HAVING`)

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp (on `HAVING`)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177905(v=office.12).aspx (on `GROUP BY`)

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp (on `GROUP BY`)

Comment: Yes, i apologize, Truck002 is a terrible table name. I was going to make a new table for each Truck. But right now I am using Truck002 for all trucks. I will change this table name ASAP once I figure out this SQL statement. Thank you very much for the links.